# Selection Sort in C ambiguity

Tags: c, sorting, swap

Below code works fine but 2nd code doesn't, I am not sure what went wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>

void swap(int *xp, int *yp)
{
    int temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[100], i, j, n, temp, min_idx, min;
    printf("\nEnter how many numbers\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\nEnter %d numbers to be sorted\n", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]); //take input

    for (i = 0; i < (n - 1); i++)
    {
        min_idx = i;
        for (j = (i + 1); j < n; j++)
            if (a[j] < a[min_idx])
                min_idx = j;
        swap(&a[min_idx], &a[i]);
    }

    printf("\nSorted array is:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("\na[%d] = %d", i, a[i]);
}
```

2nd code (only modified the swapping part but doesn't work):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a[100], i, j, n, temp, min_idx, min;
    printf("\nEnter how many numbers\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\nEnter %d numbers to be sorted\n", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        min = a[i];
        for (j = (i + 1); j < n; j++)
        {
            if (a[j] < min)
            {
                min_idx = j;
                min = a[j];
                printf("\nmin_idx = %d and j = %d", min_idx, j);
            }
        }
        temp = a[i]; //modified part
        a[i] = a[min_idx];
        a[min_idx] = a[i];

        min_idx = 0;
    }

    printf("\nSorted array is:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("\na[%d] = %d", i, a[i]);
}
```

Output is just-

```
1
1
1
1
1
```

Only modified the swap logic but not sure what goes wrong, the code doesnt work. Why does it work only if the reference (&) is used and not when normally swapped as dont in 2nd code segment? Please let me know what went wrong, TIA.

Comment: C has no references.

Comment: Clearly you changed more than that.

Comment: @bunglehead 'min' variable right? That's ok but swap logic is untouched and that's what I am concerned.

Comment: @Swordfish I thought array decayed into pointers by default. Is that what you are talking about? Please elaborate.

Comment: In the second code, pretend the array is sorted.  `min_idx = j;` never called.  What does `a[i] = a[min_idx];` do?  "only modified the swapping part" is not true.

Comment: `&` is the address-of operator and has nothing to do with "references" (whatever that might be)

Comment: ` a[min_idx = temp` instead of ` a[min_idx]=a[i]`  Typo !

Comment: @Damien Yes that was the issue thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Here, I hope it'll be easy enough to follow what I've changed in your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a[100], i, j, n, temp, min_idx, min;
    printf("\nEnter how many numbers\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\nEnter %d numbers to be sorted\n", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        min = a[i];
        min_idx = i;
        for (j = (i + 1); j < n; j++)
        {
            if (a[j] < min)
            {
                min_idx = j;
                min = a[j];
                printf("\nmin_idx = %d and j = %d", min_idx, j);
            }
        }
        if (min_idx != i) {
            temp = a[i]; //modified part
            a[i] = a[min_idx];
            a[min_idx] = temp;
        }
    }

    printf("\nSorted array is:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("\na[%d] = %d", i, a[i]);
}
```